# how to remove float leftovers in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point

I would like to remove float leftovers while retaining its type.

(i.e 3.14159f should become 3.0f)

What I can do so far is casting the type twice.

```
float f = 3.14159f;

float r = static_cast<float>(static_cast<int>(f));
```

Is this the correct way to do it? or is there any simpler way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can assign an int to a float and it would still be float.

Comment: `f = std::trunc(f)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operation of "removing leftovers" is called *truncation*. C++ provides [`std::trunc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/trunc) function to do it (include `<cmath>` header):

```
float r = std::trunc(f);
```

Comment: Can there be any performance overhead when I use trunc() instead of static_cast<int>()?

Comment: @ZackLee This is one of those instances where you should only worry about performance *after* you proved `std::trunc` is too slow for your usecase and just use if for the correctness.

Comment: @ZackLee Good chances are that the call is going to contain a single inlined instruction.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight shouldn't it be std::truncf(f) technically in order to return float and not double?

Comment: @Fanael: I did in several different versions, but forgot the msse4.1 flag.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this the correct way to do it?

No.

> or is there any simpler way?

One single cast should be sufficient:

```
float r = static_cast<int>(f);
```

---

Also as @Baum mit Augen said in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45116815/how-to-remove-float-leftovers-in-c/45116825#comment77204852_45116825):

> *"This fails for values that don't fit in an `int`"*

So using [`std::trunc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/trunc) solves that problem with correct error handling.

Comment: this should be a comment!

Comment: @SurajS In what way do you feel it fails to answer the question? It looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @SurajS Why so? There was a clear question and I answered it. Just because it is a fairly simple question that doesn't mean it is off-topic, no?

Comment: This fails for values that don't fit in an `int`.

Comment: @Baum THX. I adopted that into my answer.

Answer (score -1):

That is a correct way to do that, but you can also use floor:

```
std::cout << std::floor(3.14f); // prints 3
```